# Running ScalaZ3 on Mac

Tags: scala, z3

Running a program that uses ScalaZ3. This is on a Max with OS XAt run time I get an exception as follows

```
Could not find /lib-bin/libscalaz3.dylib
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not find /lib-bin/libscalaz3.dylib
at z3.Z3Wrapper.loadLib(Z3Wrapper.java:74)
at z3.Z3Wrapper.loadFromJar(Z3Wrapper.java:52)
at z3.Z3Wrapper.<clinit>(Z3Wrapper.java:32)
at z3.scala.Z3Config.<init>(Z3Config.scala:6)
```

Later I get a second stack trace

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: z3.Z3Wrapper.mkConfig()J
at z3.Z3Wrapper.mkConfig(Native Method)
at z3.scala.Z3Config.<init>(Z3Config.scala:6)
at thesis.z3option.Z3SessionCore$class.open(Z3SessionCore.scala:89)
```

I'm using the jar file at
   jar-releases/64/scala-2.9.1/scalaz3-3.2.c.jar
in the github respository.

---

Edit: Here are the errors I got on step (3) of the set up  process: sbt package

```
n060h152:ScalaZ3 theo$ sbt package
[info] Building project ScalaZ3 4.0a against Scala 2.9.2
[info] 
[info] == compute-checksum ==
[info] == compute-checksum ==
[info] 
[info] == compile ==
[info]   Source analysis: 0 new/modified, 0 indirectly invalidated, 0 removed.
[info] Compiling main sources...
[info] Nothing to compile.
[info]   Post-analysis: 273 classes.
[info] == compile ==
[info] 
[info] == javah ==
[info] Generating JNI C headers
[info] javah -classpath /Users/theo/Documents/ScalaZ3/target/scala_2.9.2/classes -d /Users/theo/Documents/ScalaZ3/src/c z3.Z3Wrapper
[error] Cannot find annotation method 'bytes()' in type 'scala.reflect.ScalaSignature': class file for scala.reflect.ScalaSignature not found
[error] Error: Class scala.ScalaObject could not be found.
[info] == javah ==
[error] Error running javah: Non-zero exit code.
[info] 
[info] Total time: 4 s, completed 24-May-2013 2:52:36 PM
[info] 
[info] Total session time: 6 s, completed 24-May-2013 2:52:36 PM
```

Comment: Did you follow the complete Mac setup steps from here:  https://github.com/psuter/ScalaZ3

Comment: No. I tried following them, but at step 3, I got a some errors. See the edit.